# Grafana stack line graph shows hidden series with value 0

Tags: grafana

I am using a stacked Grafana line graph and has given the option of hiding the series for values with zeros.

But yet there is a line drawn in the stacked series for a metric with value 0 (line colored in yellow). It is not shown in the legend as configured. It is not visible even in the tooltip.

Is there a way to hide the graph as well?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just set line width to 0.

[image]

Comment: But for that I should know that the metric value is 0 right?

Comment: i don't understand.

Comment: I want a line to be shown for the clarity for the ones with data.

Comment: With the 'fill' you'll see your data but the line wont be show. So You will see your all colors but yellow.

Comment: But requirement needs to have a visible separation line to show the border as well. Otherwise this would have worked.

Comment: Ok, you can't draw a 'stack' graphic and doenst display 0 values. This is how stack view works.

Answer (score 2):

- This is due to the queries for different series happen one after another and there can be instances where the queries return a different number of data points.
- The above issue can occur when some additional data gets written into the database in between queries and some series may not have values towards the end of the timestamps (null values). Therefore Grafana shows this as a drop in the series.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same confusion recently with one of my dashboards. There is an open bug with Grafana to not draw the lines for the 0 values, during the time frame that they are zero, so as not to hide other lines with value underneath.

See https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/15690#issuecomment-1276981815